# Lodash keyBy for multiple nested level arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an array of object, and i want to convert it into a map of key value pairs with the `id` as the key. However, I want to do it for both the root level and within the `recipes` attribute.

**Array `resp`**:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "recipes": [
      {
        "id": 4036
      },
      {
        "id": 4041
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "recipes": [
      {
        "id": 4052
      },
      {
        "id": 4053
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

I came across `_.keyBy()` which maps an attribute as the key, but it doesn't allow nested levels.

**Function:**

```
var respObj = _.keyBy(resp, 'id');
```

Is there an elegant solution to massage `resp` to make all the objects nested within the array use `id` as key?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a generic solution that runs `_.keyBy` recursively on arrays, and the objects inside them:

```
function deepKeyBy(arr, key) {
  return _(arr)
    .map(function(o) { // map each object in the array
      return _.mapValues(o, function(v) { // map the properties of the object
        return _.isArray(v) ? deepKeyBy(v, key) : v; // if the property value is an array, run deepKeyBy() on it
      });
    })
    .keyBy(key); // index the object by the key
}
```

I've added another level of data in the example (ingredients):

```js
function deepKeyBy(arr, key) {
  return _(arr)
    .map(function(o) {
      return _.mapValues(o, function(v) {
        return _.isArray(v) ? deepKeyBy(v, key) : v;
      });
    })
    .keyBy(key);
}

var arr = [{
  "id": "1",
  "recipes": [{
    "id": 4036,
    "ingerdients": [{
      "id": 5555555
    }, {
      "id": 5555556
    }, {
      "id": 5555557
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 4041
  }]
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "recipes": [{
    "id": 4052
  }, {
    "id": 4053
  }]
}];

var result = deepKeyBy(arr, 'id');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is awesome. Should've thought about using a recursive solution :)

Answer (score 4):

you can do it with `_.keyBy` and `_.mapValues`

```
_.chain(resp)
    .keyBy('id')
    .mapValues(function(item) {
        item.recipes = _.keyBy(item.recipes, 'id');
        return item;
    })
    .value();
```

Comment: Great solution too specifically for my use case! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could get a flattened collection of recipes, concatenate the response and then key by id:

```
var result = _.chain(resp)
    .flatMap('recipes')
    .concat(resp)
    .keyBy('id')
    .value()
```

The [**flatMap**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#flatMap) call will pluck all the recipes from the response and flatten the arrays so we're left with this:

```
[
    { "id": 4036 },
    { "id": 4041 },
    { "id": 4052 },
    { "id": 4053 }
]
```

The response is then appended to this array using [**concat**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#concat) so we then have:

```
[
    { "id": 4036 },
    { "id": 4041 },
    { "id": 4052 },
    { "id": 4053 },
    { "id": "1", recipes: ... }, 
    { "id": "2", recipes: ... } 
]
```

Finally we use [**keyBy**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#keyBy) to get the required structure .

```js
  var resp = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "recipes": [
        {
          "id": 4036
        },
        {
          "id": 4041
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "recipes": [
        {
          "id": 4052
        },
        {
          "id": 4053
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

 var result = _.chain(resp)
  .flatMap('recipes')
  .concat(resp)
  .keyBy('id')
  .value()

document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <pre id="result"></pre>
</p>
```

Comment: interesting.. how does the flatMap() and concat() work to put recipe back into the parent object?

Comment: Added an explanation.